# Rancher doesn't pick up changes in Catalog

Tags: kubernetes-helm, rancher

I had a catalog of version 1.0.0
I made changes to the catalog with the same version, rancher still shows the old catalog.

I have read that it is because Rancher's caching mechanism.

Ok, I then incremented the version to 1.0.1

Rancher still shows the old one.
Then made increment to 1.0.2, 1.0.4 ..etc.  Still the old one.

How to force Rancher to use the real catalog instead of showing some old one??
How to clear calatog cache?

rancher v2.4.3

edit: the only solution currently is to increment version in bigger steps like 1.1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have found:

Rancher doesnt provide any information about the Catalog cache or any kind of possbility to reset it.But it seems it clears the cache for the catalog once the corresponding repository deleted from the Catalog page.

**Clearing the cache:**
Delete the helm repository then wait the clear-cache mechanism to take effect. It takes ~1 min.
 Then readd the repository and it seems to work. 
Whether the new catalog is in effect can be checked in the `Preview` section on the `App Launch/Upgrade Form`.

**To be more specific:**
The caches are stored here (at least in case of dockerized Rancher):

```
/var/lib/rancher/management-state/catalog-cache
```

So -after the deletion- once you see the corresponding cache folder has been removed you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

We have a setup where Rancher-2.5.9 is used. In this Deleting a repository is not needed. A catalog refresh works fine (select the catalog, choose the menu option, and click on refresh). I can see the new version pushed a few minute back are available in the dropdown.

But unfortunately the same is not working on another setup where rancher-2.6.3 exists. Need to debug more and see if the issue is there in the setup or in the rancher version.